# Using scoreboards as varibles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In my minecraft map, I have a scoreboard, mainvars, that I made by running `/scoreboard objectives add mainvars dummy`, 
that has 1 player called var I made by running `/scoreboard add players var mainvars 5`.

I tried to test if var = 5 with `/testfor var[score_mainvars=5]`, but it doesn't work.

EDIT:but `/testfor @p[score_mainvars=5]` works? I'm confused.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a player's name in place of an @ selector. If you want to test for someone with a certain name, use the `name` argument:

```
/testfor @a[name=var,score_mainvars=5]
```

Keep in mind that @a selects player entities that exist somewhere in the world, not every single possible username. e.i. this will only work if there is actually a player called "var" currently on the world.

If you're wanting to test for a scoreboard objective value, rather than an online player, then you should use the `/scoreboard players test` command. The syntax is:

```
/scoreboard players test <player> <objective> <min> <max>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scoreboard assigns the value of a variable to each and every player.
Take for eg- 
There is a variable called money.
Now, it has no central value corresponding to the game, but it has a unique value for each and every player. And hence what you wrote later was correct.